# Beamer caption name not changing

Tags: beamer, captions

I am changing the font of my presentation to calibri, but the caption name under a figure (the "Figure" part)  isn't changing to calibri, but stays in a serif font. The \setbeamerfont{caption name}{... doesn't seem to work

Here is a mwe but it doesn't reproduce the problem... Maybe it is because I use a style?

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item list of duck items
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Duck example}%\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Has propose, here is the log on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Pq0kSSvY)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need `\centering`, figures are centred per default in beamer

Comment: See answer post comments for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer uses sans serif font, so instead of setting the main font, you need to change the sans font (I replaced the font with `papyrus` to easier see that it is working)

And as @DavidCarlisle thankfully observed:

> don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with `luatex` and especially not with `xetex`

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Papyrus}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item list of duck items
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Duck example}%\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And with `calibri`:

```
 % !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169,t]{beamer}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Calibri}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\setbeamerfont{caption name}{family=\sffamily,size=\small}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item list of duck items
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
  %\centering
  \includegraphics[width=.3\paperwidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image-duck}
  \caption{Duck example}%\label{}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: From my test on my main file, using \setsansfont{Calibri} changes it to a serif font everywhere...

Comment: @Simon Can you show your .log file (if it is too long to add to the question, try pastebin.com)

Comment: thanks, it has been added

Comment: @Simon If you look at the warnings in the log, it says that it cannot find the font `LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+Calibri(0) on input line
 105.
LaTeX Font Info:    No file T1Calibri(0).fd. on input line 105.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/Calibri(0)/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 105.`

Comment: HOOOOO!!!!! ok. so I need to tell where the font is? Should I use a complete path or a relative one? (I am on a company computer on which I don't have full control)

Comment: @Simon mmmm, to be honest I'm not really sure why it does not find your font. At the very end it says it is in `C:/Windows/Fonts/calibri.ttf`, so it should know where it is?

Comment: I tried forcing it with a explicit path, and no luck.

Comment: @Simon I asked in chat about this (https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49607039#49607039) maybe someone can help

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with luatex and especially not with xetex